# Dynamic URL binding to iframe in Knockout js

Tags: javascript, iframe, knockout.js

I am having an issue when binding ***src*** attribute to the iframe at runtime.

> iframe data-bind="visible: $root.someBoolProp(), attr:{src:$root.someProp}" /iframe

When I do console.log($root.someProp), it is logging the correct URL.(**https://dev-payment....**)

I'm not sure after rending the view it is throwing the below error with **localhost url** appended to the actual iframe URL.

**Error message:**

Refused to display 'http://localhost:62489/en/hoapayment/%22https://dev-payment-ui.azurewebsites.net/something%22' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Could someone please let me know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Could it be that `someProp` holds a url without a protocol specified? see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028545/3002584).

Comment: `someProp` holds the protocol as well. I see the complete URL along with the protocol when I do `console.log()`.

Comment: It depends where you're doing console.log() vs where you're actually using it. Looks like the url is being set as a relative one (your website url + url from root.someProp). Also, try $root.someProp() with parenthesis in the end.

Comment: One more thing I would like to add here:  When i try passing the URL directly to Iframe SRC , I'm able to see the page loading in the iframe. `console.log('Payment URL: ',paymentUrl);
            frame.attr('src', 'https://dev-payment-ui.azurewebsites.net....');`   ... But when I pass the variable to the SRC, I'm getting the above error `console.log('Payment URL: ',paymentUrl);
            frame.attr('src', paymentUrl);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with URL format. URL which is coming as part of `paymentUrl` is like **""https://dev-payment...""**. So I have to remove extra **"**.

Thanks for your answers.